# Grouping and paging in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to display some data in grid like control, in which every row will have some title and ot will also have paging. I searched around but did not found any solution.

Data will look like this

---

### row title

### item | item | item | item

### row title

### item | item | item | item

### row title

### item | item | item | item

---

First Prev next last

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Building a Grouping Grid with the ASP.NET 3.5 LinqDataSource and ListView Controls**
http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/01/building_a_grouping_grid_with.html

**Including Subheadings in a Datagrid** 
https://web.archive.org/web/20210510023010/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/072603-1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use **asp.net repeater** control for this purpose.

Please check this [article](http://www.asp101.com/articles/john/repeater/default.asp) for the walk through.

Comment: +1 - With the repeater you can also have better control over the html you want to emit.

Answer (score 0):

If you have budget, you can always check out the [Telerik RADGrid](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/grid.aspx) controls.  This will let perform the group quite easily.  It's cheap when you consider that you get support for client side /AJAX functionality, paging etc.  The control has exactly what you're looking for with [nested grid structures](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/grid.aspx#hierarchical-grids).